# Write an algorithm to find a path that traverses all edges of directed graph G exactly once

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

...You may visit nodes multiple times, if necessary. Show the run time complexity of your algorithm. This graph is not necessarily strongly connected, but starting from a node there should exist such a path.

My approach so far was to repeatedly DFS at unvisited nodes to find the node with the highest post number as this will be part of the source node in a meta graph.

Then repeatedly DFS on the reverse graph to find the sink node meta graph.

Then run the Eulerian path algorithm until we exhaust all of the edges, backtracking if a path leads to a dead end.

I cant figure out how to proceed from here.

Hi, I came up with this. Can someone please verify it?

```
function edge_dfs(vertex u, graph, path, num_edges) {

    if num_edges == 0 { // Found a path. 
        return true;
    }


    for all neighbors n of u {

        if exists((u, n)) == true {
            num_edges--
            exists((u, n)) = false
            path.append((n))
            if edge_dfs(n, g, p, num_edges) == true:
                return true
            else:
                num_edges++ // Backtrack if this edge was unsuccessful. 
                exists((u, n)) = true
                path.pop()
        }
    }

    return false // No neighbors or No valid paths from this vertex. 
}


repeatedly do dfs and fine a source component
node: call it s. 

path = array{s}
exists((u, v)) = true for all edges (u, v) in graph
num_edges = number of edges in graph

if edge_dfs(s, graph, path, num_edges) == true:
    Path is the elements in array 'path' in order. 
else:
    Such a path does not exist.
```

And this is O(|E| + |V|) as it is just a DFS of all of the edges.

Comment: I only posted pseudo code.